# Drop down list display 0

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

[image]

```
 strsql = "Select Sup_Name + '-----'  + Sup_Code As Supdisplay , Sup_Code From kjm_supplier_profile Order By Sup_Name  "
 cmd = New MySqlCommand(strsql, Conn)
 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
 strddl.DataSource = rdr
 strddl.DataTextField = "Supdisplay"
 strddl.DataValueField = "Sup_Code"
 strddl.DataBind()

 strddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select Supplier", ""))

 rdr.Close()
```

This is to bind the data to the drop-down list with two data. But the drop-down list display 0

Comment: What data do you get when executing this Query in SQL?

Comment: Is the connection actually open? Did you call `Conn.Open()`?

Comment: I want get the Supplier Name and Supplier Code

Comment: The connect is actually open. I did call Conn.Open()

Comment: Try dumping the data in a data table and see if you're getting the correct data. Something like `DataTable dt  = new DataTable();  dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());`

Answer (score 0):

```
 strsql = "Select Sup_Name + '-----'  + Sup_Code As Supdisplay , Sup_Code From kjm_supplier_profile Order By Sup_Name  "
 cmd = New MySqlCommand(strsql, Conn)
 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
 strddl.DataSource = rdr
 strddl.DataTextField = "Sup_Name "
 strddl.DataValueField = "Supdisplay "
 strddl.DataBind()

 strddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select Supplier", ""))

 rdr.Close()
```